# How Hyper-V server 2012 shares processor usage over virtual machine?

Tags: virtual-machines, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012

I have a Hyper-V server 2012 installed on my physical server (bare-metal). For testing purposes I created 2 VM machines (windows 7) and began testing server processor usage while VM runs at 100% processor usage. For tests I tried using "HeavyLoad" computer stress program as well as generating a complex image using "Blender" program for 3D rendering.
The thing I noticed was that VM at full processor usage barely shows any usage on server processor. Usage on server processor only spikes up when I connect to VM using Hyper-V manager console. I tried the same test using remote desktop connection but the load didn't spike up while connected to the machine.
What I want to know is how hyper-v server shares CPU time over virtual machines? Thank you.

I use this powershell command to check CPU load:

Get-WmiObject win32_processor | select LoadPercentage  |fl